# Cookie management with persistence

Tags: php, serialization, cookies

PEAR's HTTP_Request2 - I've got a HTTP_Request2_CookieJar object that I wish to save for a later session.

The [manual](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2_CookieJar.html#methodserialize) for HTTP_Request2 says it implements the serializable interface. The source the manual refers to does indeed show implementations of the serialize() and unserialize() contracts.

But that source is Feb 2011. The latest August 2011 source no longer implements the serializable interface.

Serializing the object with using PHP's serialize()/unserialize() appears to be a nightmare from some searching I've done on it.

The nice thing about HTTP_Request2's cookie jar was it automatically handled cookies during the session, but I need them to persist between sessions and don't really want to have to spend a night writing pages of code to do so.

Is there an easiest path to take here?

Comment: Extend it and implement serializable yourself?  Can you make the request use your cookie jar instead of its native one?  The interface looks straightforward.

Comment: I'm a bit cautious to do reimplement it as there must have been good reason the functionality was removed to start with--I'm guessing it didn't work properly. I'm not familiar with the serializable interface and don't particularly wish to learn it right now, I just wish to use it.

Comment: Contact the author and ask them why it was removed and if they plan on putting it back.  If they're putting it back, you can always use the older version and upgrade once the functionality has been replace.

Comment: The easiest way is to email these guys and ask. Alexey is very responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to note the question gives misleading info.

HTTP_Request2_CookieJar implemented Serializable interface from the very beginning and this was never removed, [see this SVN annotation](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/HTTP_Request2/trunk/HTTP/Request2/CookieJar.php?view=annotate).

Comment: Interesting... I do note there is no August 2011 source that I refer to and I do tend to recall HTTP_Request2_CookieJar at that stage was implementing another interface. Maybe I stumbled across a temporary check-in? Anyway, it's there now and that's all that counts, so I'll close off this question.

Answer (score 0):

By default, session cookies are not serialized.  You must call serializeSessionCookies(true) on the CookieJar object before serializing.  See [HTTP_Request2_CookieJar::serializeSessionCookies](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2_CookieJar.html#methodserializeSessionCookies).

The code for [serializing](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/HTTP_Request2/trunk/HTTP/Request2/CookieJar.php?view=markup):353 and [unserializing](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pear/packages/HTTP_Request2/trunk/HTTP/Request2/CookieJar.php?view=markup):376 is present in March 2012, so maybe the developer put it back in.